# How is this 2D array being sized by FOR loops?

Tags: python, arrays

**Question background:**

This is the first piece of Python code I've looked at and as such I'm assuming that my thread title is correct in explaining what this code is actually trying to achieve i.e setting a 2D array.

**The code:**

The code I'm looking at sets the size of a 2D array based on two for loops:

```
n = len(sentences)
values = [[0 for x in xrange(n)] for x in xrange(n)]

   for i in range(0, n):
     for j in range(0, n):
        values[i][j] = self.sentences_intersection(sentences[i], sentences[j])
```

I could understand it if each side of the array was set with using the length property of the `sentences` variable, unless this is in effect what `xrange` is doing by using the loop size based on the length?

Any helping with explaing how the array is being set would be great.

Comment: for starters, this seems to be copy/pasted of a larger class definition to the point where the code can't run by itself -- the indention of the `for` block is wrong, and the `self.sentences_intersection` is not known. As we don't know what this very method does, we can't really tell what the code does. Please include more of the original code, and also provide a sample for the value of `sentences`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is actually a bit redundant.

Firstly you need to realize that `values` is not an array, it is a list. A list is a dynamically sized one-dimensional structure.

The second line of the code uses a nested list comprehension to create one list of size n, each element of which is itself a list consisting of n zeros.

The second loop goes through this list of lists, and sets each element according to whatever `sentences_intersection` does.

The reason this is redundant is because lists don't need to be pre-allocated. Rather than doing two separate iterations, really the author should just be building up the lists with the correct values, then appending them.

This would be better:

```
n = len(sentences)

values = []
for i in range(0, n):
  inner = []
  for j in range(0, n):
    inner.append(self.sentences_intersection(sentences[i], sentences[j]))
  values.append(inner)
```

but you could actually do the whole thing in the list comprehension if you wanted:

```
values = [[self.sentences_intersection(sentences[i], sentences[j]) for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
```